# MVC jquery bundling does not evalute C# code if you have one

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a jquery that I want to bundle it and inside the jquery I refer to tempdata like

`var redirectToUrl = '@TempData[Constants.REDIRECT_TO_URL]'` .

So when I put it directly on the layout page, it works as expected and the tempdate evalutes but when I put it in a separate js file , it never gets evaluated . Any idea

Comment: why would you expect it to work in a js file? JS runs in client

Comment: js files are not Razor files, thus @ syntax doesn't work.

Comment: I know that but it is loaded on the page and it should be tried the same way as if it were written on the page

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. if I get it right, js files are just transported to the client and never loaded on the page on the server

Comment: you got it right, same as css files or media resources

Comment: Javascript is handled as a simple file resource, not as a page handled by the ASP.NET engine and routed to a controller. It's possible to make the ASP.NET engine handle all requests, and add routes to handle the Javascript file as a view by a controller so that it can run razor tags, but that seems like overkill just to get some data into the page.

Comment: If you want to add dynamic information to your JS files, you could always expose some properties on a JS object (with closures), and set them in your cshtml page before calling any of your functions.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript where you want to use your razor syntax would have to be on the .cshtml page

a .js file by itself does not know anything about razor syntax, but if the javascript is actually on the .cshtml page then you have access to @variables